# How to turn motor on/ff automatically using Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, sms

My project involves sending SMS to turn the system on or off manually, `Motor on`, `Motor off` but I wanted an option to make the system run by itself without having to manually turn the motor on or off myself. Hence `Auto on`. This auto can be turned off by `Auto off`. I don't know how to make the system run while on `Auto on` to turn the motor off by switching my soil moisture probe from the dry soil into the wet soil and vice versa from wet to dry and turning the motor on.  If the condition of `SensorValue` is >= `Maxdryness` I want it to stop and only turn on when the value is < the `Maxdryness`.

```
 { 
  auto_flag = 1;
  message1 = "System is now automatic";
  send_message(message1); // Send a sms back to confirm that the motor is turned auto

  if (readSoil() >= Maxdryness)
    {
  Serial.println("Soil is good.\r"); 
  digitalWrite(wetSoil, HIGH);
  digitalWrite (drySoil, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPin1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPin2,LOW);
  delay(1000);
    }

  else
   {
  Serial.println("Low Soil Moisture detected.\r");
  digitalWrite(wetSoil, LOW);
  digitalWrite (drySoil, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorPin1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorPin2,LOW);
    }
   
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("Soil Moisture = "); 
  Serial.println(readSoil());
  delay(1000);//take a reading every second 
   
  auto_flag = 0;
 }
```

I am trying to make the `SensorValue`  variable update if the condition of `SensorValue < Maxdryness` or `SensorValue >= Maxdryness` is false at any time. I want to be able to switch my moisture sensor between dry and wet soil and make it turn my motor on or off as needed automatically.

Comment: Variables don't update themselves - ever. If you want the program to keep updating a variable, then you have to make it do that.

Comment: For that reason, microcontroller programs are often written as `void loop() {check everything; update everything;}` - no long while loops inside the `loop` function, the program remembers what it's doing in variables

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing hysteresis in your code, hense your add long delays everywhere. One of the simplest way would be to add global boolean flag - "motor on" and maintain it accordingly (set it `true` when you turn on and vice versa). Then you act based on that flag - if motor on you only check when `SensorValue >= Maxdryness` and when it is off you only check for `SensorValue < Mindryness`. You need to make `Mindryness` less than `Maxdryness` - that will create hysteresis. How big is that gap, it depends on your conditions, make too big and it will overflow, make it too small and it will jerk motor too often. This way you would not need long delays and system would still work smoothly.

As a safety you may want to measure how long motor is on and shut system down if it did not rich level in some long time, to avoid overflow if something went wrong.